# PrimeNG (chart.js) chart legend to display title and legend in a SINGLE line on top

Tags: typescript, chart.js, legend, primeng

I have a chart.js based primeNG donut chart derivative and I am trying to display legend better.
What I want is the legend title is in the top left corner and rest of the legend in the top right corner both shown on THE SAME line.
Nearest I could get with configuring the legend is :

```
legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      align: 'start',
      title: {
        display: true,
        color: this.centerLabelColor,
        text: 'Coverage Rate',
        padding:0,
      },
      labels: {
        color: this.centerLabelColor,
        boxWidth: 13,
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding:3,
      },
    },
```

Which gets me this:

[image]

**But I want this:**

[image]

I am sure there is a way to make a fake legend outside of the chart and package both as a component, but the point of this question is to configure the chart's legend not disable it and make your own.

Here is the code for that pic:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xq4q7h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgauge-chart%2Fgauge-chart.component.ts